# Install cx_Oracle on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, python, oracle

I'm trying to install cx_Oracle for Python on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit).

I've installed Instant Client Package from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

I did it using alien for converting to dpm and then used `dpkg -i`.

I've installed cx_Oracle from (CentOS 5 x86_64 RPM (Oracle 11g, Python 2.7)):
http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/

I did it using alien for converting to dpm and then used `dpkg -i`.

However, trying to import cx_Oracle just reports:

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  import cx_Oracle
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7
sudo mv site-packages/cx_Oracle* dist-packages/
sudo rmdir site-packages/
sudo ln -s dist-packages site-packages
sudo ldconfig
```

Thanks to http://bayo.opadeyi.net/2011/07/setting-up-cxoracle-on-ubuntu-1104.html